# Issue with Using JWT for Authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc, bearer-token

I'm encountering an issue while implementing authentication using JSON Web Token (JWT) in ASP.NET Core MVC. I have an ASP.NET Core API with a login endpoint that returns a JWT in response to user login. Here's the code for my login endpoint in the API:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginUserDTO userDTO)
{
    // ... (omission for brevity)
    return Accepted(new TokenRequest { Token = await _authManager.CreateToken(), RefreshToken = await _authManager.CreateRefreshToken() });
}    

public async Task<string> CreateToken()
{
    var signingCredentials = GetSigningCredentials();
    var claims = await GetClaims();
    var token = GenerateTokenOptions(signingCredentials, claims);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}

private JwtSecurityToken GenerateTokenOptions(SigningCredentials signingCredentials, List<Claim> claims)
{
    var jwtSettings = _configuration.GetSection("Jwt");
    var expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(
        jwtSettings.GetSection("lifetime").Value));

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: jwtSettings.GetSection("Issuer").Value,
        claims: claims,
        expires: expiration,
        signingCredentials: signingCredentials
        );

    return token;
}

private async Task<List<Claim>> GetClaims()
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _user.UserName)
    };

    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(_user);

    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }

    return claims;
}

private SigningCredentials GetSigningCredentials()
{
    var key = _configuration.GetSection("Jwt:KEY").Value;
    var secret = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));

    return new SigningCredentials(secret, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
}
```

Now, in my MVC project, I have a Login method that calls the API for login and securely saves the token:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    // ... (omission for brevity)

    var token = await GetAccessToken(model); // call tha API to get the token

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        SaveToken(token);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
    }
    return View(model);
} 
private void SaveTokenSecurely(string token)
{
    // Puoi salvare il token in un cookie sicuro, ad esempio:
    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = true,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
    };

    Response.Cookies.Append("AccessToken", token, cookieOptions);
}
```

Here's how I've configured authentication in the MVC project:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     var jwtSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt");
     var key = jwtSettings.GetSection("Key").Value;
     var issuer = jwtSettings.GetSection("Issuer").Value;

     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
     {
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         ValidateAudience = false,
         ValidateLifetime = true,
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         ValidIssuer = issuer,
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)),

     };
 });
```

The appsettings.json file is the same for the API and MVC project:

```
  "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "MY.PROJECT.Api",
    "lifetime": 15,
    "Key": "SUPERR STRONG KEY"
  }
```

The problem is that despite successful login and obtaining the token, when I try to access my Privacy page with the [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] attribute, I still get a 401 error. I've verified that the "Administrator" role is present in the payload of my token.

I checked the token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and [here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oChAS.png). If the `secret base64 encoded` is not checked I get Invalid Signature.

Also I tried to call `Privacy()` from [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) setting the `Authorization` > `Bearer Token` > `and then the token`, this works as expected.

I'm aware that there are several questions on Stack Overflow regarding JWT token unauthorized errors in ASP.NET Core MVC, and I've already looked into some of them:

- [JWT Token Error 401 Unauthorized in .NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784211/jwt-token-error-401-unauthorized-in-net-core-3-1)
- [ASP.NET Core JWT Authentication Always Throwing 401 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976960/asp-net-core-jwt-authentication-always-throwing-401-unauthorized)
- [Getting 401 Unauthorized ASP.NET Core 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72071601/getting-401-unauthorized-asp-net-core-6)
- [ASP.NET Core 5 and 6 JWT Authentication Always Throws HTTP 401 Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837552/asp-net-core-5-and-6-jwt-authentication-is-always-throws-http-401-code)

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue might be or how I can resolve it? Thanks in advance for the help!

### Temporary solution

I solve it adding this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     var jwtSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt");
     var key = jwtSettings.GetSection("Key").Value;
     var issuer = jwtSettings.GetSection("Issuer").Value;

     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
     {
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         ValidateAudience = false,
         ValidateLifetime = true,
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         ValidIssuer = issuer,
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)),
     };
     options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
     {
         OnMessageReceived = context =>
         {
             var token = context.Request.Cookies["AccessToken"];
             context.Token = token;
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         }
     };
 });
```

although this is not a very good solution. Could you please provide a complete answer regarding my problem?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind: I&#39;d expect jwt tokens to be in the header of the request in the authorization attribute, not in the cookie. The client therefore should always include it in every request.
That&#39;s probably why it works with the postman try, because as said it&#39;s in the authorization header, not somewhere in the cookie

Edit: or you might need to add some code that the token is taken from the cookie, that should be possible somewhere in the startup, not sure how exactly atm

Comment: @DerDingens I solve it adding this: `options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents{ OnMessageReceived = context => {  var token = context.Request.Cookies["AccessToken"]; context.Token = token;  return Task.CompletedTask;  }};`  although this is not a very good solution. Could you please provide a complete answer regarding my problem?

Comment: I can't really, as I don't know one for that use case.
I think yours should fit your case and is good for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @DerDingens (in comment) is right, to sum up:

1. This will never work if HTTP requests does not contain header:

```
'Authorization: Bearer <JWT_TOKEN>'
```

Because this is how JWT works:
'JWT auth' ->  means 'Authorization: Bearer ...' header must be present
if You use cookie, then:
'Cookie' Auth -> Cookie must be present

2. In Your specific case (store JWT in cookie):
   I think that I saw several times on the internet similar problem,
   you can solve this with code below. Its very similar to Your solution.

**Solution**: Add middleware that sets header 'Authorization: Bearer'  before UseAuth.. middleware, for example:

```
// Add this middleware before authorization
// obviously 'AccessToken' is Your cookie name
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var token = context.Request.Cookies["AccessToken"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) &&
        !context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
    {
        context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    }

    await next();
});
```

Comment: thank you for this solution. How safe and is it a good aproach to call tha api like in my case to do the authentication?

Answer (score 1):

.net7 has simplified this.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(); // new feature
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
var app = builder.Build();
```

https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-dotnet-7-for-authentication-and-authorization/

Try to use the Microsoft defaults where possible so things like `dotnet user-jwts` work

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/authentication/jwt-authn?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows